# decorating recursive functions

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator that I wrote that will time a given function.  It seems to work well with any function, except for recursive functions.

Decorator:

```
def tictoc(repeats=3, loops=1):
    def t(func):
        from functools import partial, wraps
        import timeit
        @wraps(func)
        def timer(*args, **kargs):
            elapsed = timeit.repeat(partial(func, *args, **kargs), repeat = repeats, number=loops)
            mine = min(elapsed)
            print "%s finished in %.5fs (%d loops, %d times) with %.5fs per loop" % (func.__name__, mine, loops, repeats, mine/loops)
        return timer
    return t
```

the recursive function is the basic Fibonacci algorithm.

```
@tictoc()
def fib(i):
    return ( 0 if i == 0 else
             1 if i == 1 else
             fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) )
fib(15)
```

The program fails with the following error

```
fib finished in 0.00000s (1 loops, 3 times) with 0.00000s per loop
fib finished in 0.00000s (1 loops, 3 times) with 0.00000s per loop
fib finished in 0.00000s (1 loops, 3 times) with 0.00000s per loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decor.py", line 61, in <module>
    [fib(x) for x in range(1,50)]
  File "/home/grout/Dropbox/Python/tictoc.py", line 7, in timer
    elapsed = timeit.repeat(partial(func, *args, **kargs), repeat = repeats, number=loops)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 233, in repeat
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer).repeat(repeat, number)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 221, in repeat
    t = self.timeit(number)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 194, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/timeit.py", line 100, in inner
    _func()
  File "decor.py", line 59, in fib
    fib(i-1) + fib(i-2) )
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

What I don't understand is how the decorator executes a few times and then fails.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am going to settle on this

```
def tictoc(func, repeats=3, loops=100, *args, **kargs):
    elapsed = timeit.repeat(lambda: func(*args, **kargs), repeat = repeats, number = loops)
    mine = min(elapsed)
    return "%s finished in %.5fs (%s loops, repeated %s times): %.5fs best time per loop"         %(func.__name__, mine, loops, repeats, mine/loops)
```

Answer (score 6):

The function your decorator returns doesn't return anything. So although `fib` is supposed to return an integer, your wrapped `fib` returns `None`. It works a few times because a few recursive calls are made without checking the results of `fib`, but when it needs the result (when it has to add two of them together) you get the exception.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.  However, I run into another problem.  The decorator now times each individual function call and prints the results to the stdout.  I would rather time each call silently and return a cumulative time.  However, I am at a loss how implement this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that adding each runtime to a list (timeit.repeats returns a list), then returning min(min(cumulative_times)) would be the way to do it.

Comment: just do something like: "start=time.time(); for i in xrange(repeat): func(*args,**kwargs); time_taken=time.time()-start"